# Is It Possible to Add Multiple Repository Items in a Gridview Cells using DEVEXPRESS?

Tags: c#, repository, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have Datatable and I have to add Two repository items to same cell

```
     DataTable dtbl = null;
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtbl = new DataTable();
        dtbl.Columns.Add("T1");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("T2");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("T3");

        dtbl.Rows.Add("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
        dtbl.Rows.Add("Test4", "Test5", "Test6");
        dtbl.Rows.Add("Test7", "Test8", "Test9");

        gridControl1.DataSource = dtbl.DefaultView;
        gridView1.CustomRowCellEdit += new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventHandler(gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit);
    }

    void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        RepositoryItemButtonEdit rebBtn = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
        RepositoryItemComboBox rebcmb= new RepositoryItemComboBox();
        rebBtn.AutoHeight = false;
        rebcmb.AutoHeight = false;
        e.RepositoryItem = rebBtn;
        e.RepositoryItem = rebcmb;
    }
```

I have to add Button and Combobox is it Possible .

```
      The image i uploaded is a WPF gridColumn , is this possible in DEVEXPRESS GridControl
```

[image]

```
          This is Devexpress Gridcontrol .. here i created Two sepetate columns..
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two RepositoryItems active at the same time. You could use a ComboBox RepositoryItem and add an additional button to the Buttons property though. You could then react to the ButtonClick or ButtonPressed events.

Comment: Add a TextBox to?? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I created a Gridcontrol and i have datatable which is used to fill the gridview and now i set gridcontrol1.datasource = datatable.defaultview  now the gridview is loaded and i want to add a COMBOBOX and a TEXTEDIT in same cell is this possible ..

Comment: see my question again i uploaded a pic

Comment: So these are WPF controls? I don't know for DX WPF but for DX WinForm GridView you can only have one RepositoryItem activate at a time

Comment: @ChristopheKeller may i ask how to set or add adtional button ?
can refer to my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864644/add-custom-button-in-gridview-auto-filter-row