# How to Get Element Names from XElement Using C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a Xml and i have to get the element name

```
 <Data>
     <Test key="G" modifier="control" /> 
     <Test1  key="E" modifier="control" /> 
     <Test3 /> 
     <Test4 /> 
 </Data>

 XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("..\\Cmd.xml");
 IEnumerable<XElement> xeCmdData = Cmd.XPathSelectElements(".//Data");

 foreach (XElement xeData in xeCmdData)
 {
     // here i am getting the whole xml how to get Element name  ... 
     // Like <Data> 
     //          <Test key="G" modifier="control" /> 
     //          <Test1  key="E" modifier="control" /> 
     //          <Test3 /> 
     //          <Test4 />  
     //      </Data>
 }
```

How to get Element names ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("..\\Cmd.xml");
IEnumerable<string> names = xd.XPathSelectElements("//Data/*")      
                              .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName);
```

Or without XPath

```
IEnumerable<string> names = xd.Descendants("Data")      
                              .Elements()
                              .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName);
```

Result:

```
Test
Test1
Test3
Test4
```

Comment: sir pls see this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333442/is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-repository-items-in-a-gridview-cells-using-devexp

Comment: @user2046631 sorry, but I haven't used DevExpress for several years. I suggest you to go on DevExpress forum with this question